# Apache Kylin website http://kylin.apache.org/ is showing Apache Cassandra Related Information

Tags: cassandra, kylin

**Apache Kylin** website **http://kylin.apache.org**/ is showing **Apache Cassandra**  related information only. Recently only i observed this change. If any one knows why it's like this please put your comments.

[image]

Thank You

## Edit1

just now it is changed to tomcat site

[image]

## Edit2

it's fine now
[image]

Comment: now it's fine. it's showing the actual website

Comment: I didn't see such an issue. It looks like a temporary DNS pollution

Comment: this issue was there for more than one days. i already mentioned it came to normal one.today also i observed this issue.